# How do I round a positive and negative decimal in JSTL?

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, decimal, rounding

I have two numbers that I need to round to 4 decimal places in JSTL. One is positive:

```
40.7615811
40.7616
```

and the other is negative:

```
-73.9940841
-73.9941
```

Both need to be rounded to 4 decimal places, as on the second line of each example.

Is there a clean way to do this in JSTL or do I need to do this in a controller class or JSP scriptlet?

Answer (score 11):

You can use the [`formatNumber`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/products/products/jsp/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fmt/formatNumber.html) tag in the fmt (`http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt`) namespace.

For example

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" prefix="fmt" %>

<fmt:formatNumber value="${foo}" pattern="0.0000"/>
```